# Using class and struct

Tags: class, struct, racket

```
class Account:
        let id
        let type
        let balance
    
        # Account(nat?, account_type?, num?) -> Account?
        # Constructs an account with the given ID number, account type, and
        # balance. The balance cannot be negative.
        def __init__(self, id, type, balance):
            if balance < 0: error('Account: negative balance')
            if not account_type?(type): error('Account: unknown type')
            self.id = id
            self.type = type
            self.balance = balance
    
        struct customer:
            let name
            let bank_account
```

The above class and struct are given. My understanding is that we have to substitute the Account class in place of `bank_account` in struct. The purpose is to create a function that would add a new bank account information into the existing or empty array every time a function is called. I just tried it the following way and it didn't seem to work. Any suggestions or tips would be appreciated. The language I use was DSSL2. Thanks.

```
def open_account(name, type, customers):
           let newacc = customer(name, Account(id, type, balance))
           newacc.name = name
           newacc.Account.type = type
           newacc.Account.balance = 0
           if len.customers == 0: newacc.Account.id = 1
           else: newacc.Account.id = customers[len.customers-1].Account.id + 1
           customers = customers + newacc
```

Comment: Why is this tagged racket? What language is it?

Comment: @mmmmmm It's the "Data Structures Student Language", a Racket language package. It doesn't have its own tag.

Comment: Assigning to `customers` doesn't modify the array (DSSL2 does not have pass-by-reference). You need to use one of the mutating methods, such as `push_back`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not substitute `Account` for anything; you should set the field `bank_account` to an instance of `Account`.
That's what the struct creation does for you, so you don't need to think about it.

You need to determine the id first, and the field access syntax is `object.field`, not `field.object` or `object.type.field`.

Also, assigning to `customers` only changes the value of that variable, not the value of the object it represents (DSSL does not have call-by-reference).
You need to use one of the mutating methods, such as `push_back`.

And the struct-creation syntax is

```
struct_name { field1: value1, field2: value2, field3: value3 }
```

So (thoroughly untested), something like this:

```
def open_account(name, type, customers):
    if customers.empty?:
        id = 1
    else:
        id = customers[customers.len-1].id + 1
    let newcustomer = customer { name: name, bank_account: Account(id, type, 0) }
    customers.push_back(newcustomer)
```